# Simultaneously moving and renaming files in Red Hat

Tags: linux, rename, mv

I'm running Red Hat Release 6.5 (Santiago). The problem I'm facing is that I have a bunch of files in the following directory structure:

```
temp2
├── ABC
│   └── temp2
│       └── temp2.txt
└── DEF
    └── temp2
        └── temp2.txt
```

I'm trying to change it to the structure as below, but have no idea how to get it done.

```
temp2
├── ABC.txt
└── DEF.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a small script file to do your rename/move: call it `rnmv`, say, and put the following command into it:

```
f="${1#./}"; echo mv "$f" "${f%%/*}.${f##*.}"
```

Don't forget to `chmod +x rnmv`. Then go to the root directory and call `rnmv` from a `find` command:

```
cd {wherever temp2 root is}
find . -name "temp2.txt" -exec rnmv "{}" \;
```

When you are happy that the correct `mv` commands are being created, remove the `echo` from `rnmv` and your rename/move will be done.

One final task is to remove the empty subdirectories:

```
find . -name temp2 -exec rmdir "{}" \;
```

This is safe, as `rmdir` will not remove a directory with files in it. Depending on the order of finding the directories, you may need to repeat the command for structures like ABC/temp2/temp2, as the temp2 will not be empty until the second is deleted.

Note that if ABC, say, has more that one temp2.txt file in its subdirectories, each `mv` command will overwrite the previous ABC.txt, and only the last found will be left afterwards.

Comment: Hi, the right commands seem to get `echo`ed, but the files don't seem to be moved for some reason.

Comment: You need to delete `echo` in front of `mv` in the script file: sorry if this was less than clear.

Comment: Aagh. I seem to have read past that without realizing it. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
mv /temp2/ABC/temp2/temp2.txt /temp2/ABC.txt
mv /temp2/DEF/temp2/temp2.txt /temp2/DEF.txt
```

Depending on where the high-level temp2 directory is - I cannot tell from your example.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I have the same structure for hundreds of files; I'm looking for some sort of script.